# Whats the probability of surviving Russian roulette as the first shooter if there are n such that (n >2) people playing?

Tags: probability

Before i begin, clarification of the rules:
-6 chamber revolver. 1 chamber contains a bullet, 5 are empty.
-When a player spins, spinning is mandatory for the next player, such that the spin generated is fairly large.

note: This is under the assumption that no one will cheat.

The problem is relatively simple when considering only two players. By recognizing the application of the infinite geometric sequence sum;
p(first player lives) = 5/11
p(second player lives) =6/11

However, when we consider more than two people things become more complicated- infinite geometric sum can't be used.

e.g. if three people, the possible outcomes will be:
(5/6)(1/6) + (5/6)(5/6)(1/6) + (5/6)(5/6)(5/6)(5/6)(1/6) + (5/6)^(5)(1/6)

Notice how the terms initially increase by a ratio of 5/6, but when everyone has shot and the first shooter must take their turn again, the ratio is then (5/6)^(2). After that it goes back to 5/6. This same thing happens when there are 4,5,6.....n shooters

I don't know how to get through this so i can derive a general expression for n people. Im assuming combinations have a role, but i can't see it. Someone please help!

Comment: This needs clarification.  What rules are you following?  One bullet in six chambers spinning after each non-lethal try?  If so, I'd just treat the other $n-1$ players as a block.  Each round is then player $1$ pulls the trigger and then, if $1$ is lucky, the block has to try.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to mention the type of game being played.
One bullet, other 5 chambers are empty. After a person has shot, you are free to spin it as you like. the probability of separate shots is always independent.

Comment: I suggest:  edit your question to include the rules of the game.  I wouldn't make spinning optional, it just confuses things.  For example, the probabilities of successive shots are only independent if the second player spins.  Of course, it is always to your advantage to spin so adding the option is just a red herring (unless you want to allow your players to act sub-optimally).

Comment: If the shots are independent and if each shot has $1-p=\frac16$ chances to be fatal, then the probability that Player 1 dies at its $(k+1)$th shot conditionally on the fact that Player 1 is forced to draw their $k$ first shots and survived them, is $p^{n-1}(1-p)$ and the probability that Player 1 needed to draw their $k$th shot is $p^{n(k-1)}$ hence Player 1 dies with probability
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)p^{n-1}p^{n(k-1)}=(1-p)p^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{nk}=\frac{(1-p)p^{n-1}}{1-p^n}$$ and Player 1 lives with probability $$1-\frac{(1-p)p^{n-1}}{1-p^n}=\frac{1-p^{n-1}}{1-p^n}$$

Comment: Likewise, for each $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$, the probability that Player $i$ dies at its $(k+1)$th shot conditionally on the fact that Player $i$ is forced to draw their $k$ first shots and survived them, is $(1-p)p^{n-1}$ and the probability that Player $i$ needed to draw their $k$th shot is $p^{n(k-1)+i-1}$ hence Player $i$ dies with probability
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)p^{n-1}p^{n(k-1)+i-1}=\frac{(1-p)p^{n+i-2}}{1-p^n}$$